# Creating a aggregation function on Oracle 10g returning unhelpful error

Tags: string, oracle, oracle10g, aggregate-functions, ora-06553

I've got some help and was led to [this page](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#collect) and [this explanation](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306#8fd65), which should contain a efficient way to aggregate things.

It suggest to use de `COLLECT` function and some other custom things. I'm trying get along with it, but the error messages (plus my newbness) aren't the most helpful.

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (
    p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab, 
    p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
END tab_to_string;
```

And my tests:

```
with my_table as
(
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'ab' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'bb' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'a' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'db' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'b' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'bfdd' as prodcode from dual
)
select
    usrid, 
    tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(prodcode) AS t_varchar2_tab)) AS codes
from
    my_table
group by
    usrid
```

Would give me an `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TAB_TO_STRING'`

This is pretty much copy-and-past from the source I mention in the beginning, and the function makes sense for me.. what am I missing?

thanks!

**[EDIT]** Codo has figured that one of the problems was Oracle understanding the `'a'` as a *char*, rather than *varchar*. This brought the question to the real issue. I updated it so it is focused.

Comment: if you exclude the IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF; what happens?

Comment: @FlorinGhita No changes.. same error. Idea?

Comment: @filippo: Your example is no longer working. If all values in the column `prodcode` have the same length, it's uses the type `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. Aside from that, have you tried `tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(prodcode) AS t_varchar2_tab), ',')` as I've proposed yesterday? (On Oracle 11g, it's working anyway.)

Comment: @Codo sorry! missed that, re-edited it to put it back in order. And yeah, I tried that comma and the result is the same `ORA-06553`. I'll try to alter the function so it only has one argument and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I don't really understand, Oracle thinks that the `PRODCODE` column of your synthetic table isn't a VARCHAR2 column. If you slightly modify one of the `PRODCODE` values, it'll work:

```
with my_table as
(
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'ab' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'b' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user1' as usrid, 'c' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'd' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'e' as prodcode from dual union
    select 'user2' as usrid, 'f' as prodcode from dual
)
select
    usrid, 
    tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(prodcode) AS t_varchar2_tab)) AS codes
from
    my_table
group by
    usrid
```

Comment: I suspect that `'a'` is of `CHAR` type

Comment: Phew, that's super lame, but did the trick. No the error I've got is the `PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments`. Thoughts on that?

Comment: On Oracle 11g, if I change 'a' to 'ab', it works without any further changes. I can only guess: possibly you have the explicitly specify the second parameter `p_delimiter` in 10g.

Comment: @Codo: in 10g, the COLLECT syntax is not valid.

Comment: @Benoit: Why not? It was introduced with 10g (see [SQL reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions020.htm#sthref1146)).

Comment: @Codo: Sorry, I was mistaken, confused with `LISTAGG`.

Comment: @Codo You were right, that was one problem. But is not the real issue. Now the test behaves the same as querying the real table, though the error persists. I've updated the question.